# Defining a matrix with unknown size in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use a matrix in my Python code but I don't know the exact size of my matrix to define it.

For other matrices, I have used `np.zeros(a)`, where `a` is known.

What should I do to define a matrix with unknown size?

Comment: But... In some point you will know the size... Could you add a parameter and then give the value... Maybe?

Comment: How are you intending to fill the matrix, until you know its size?

Comment: What's the point in defining an array if you don't know its size?  It's inefficient to 'grow' one incrementally.

Comment: Another way to put the question - what are you going to do with the array before you do know its size?  Eventually what determines its size?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, maybe an approach is to use a `python list` and append to it, up until it has the desired size, then cast it to a `np array`

#### pseudocode:

```
matrix = []
while matrix not full:
    matrix.append(elt)

matrix = np.array(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that tries to modify the `np.array`, and expand if it encounters an `IndexError`:

```
x = np.random.normal(size=(2,2))

r,c = (5,10)

try:
    x[r,c] = val
except IndexError:
    r0,c0 = x.shape
    r_ = r+1-r0
    c_ = c+1-c0
    if r > 0:
        x = np.concatenate([x,np.zeros((r_,x.shape[1]))], axis = 0)
    if c > 0:
        x = np.concatenate([x,np.zeros((x.shape[0],c_))], axis = 1)
```

There are problems with this implementation though: First, it makes a copy of the array and returns a concatenation of it, which translates to a possible bottleneck if you use it many times. Second, the code I provided only works if you're modifying a single element. You could do it for slices, and it would take more effort to modify the code; or you can go the whole nine yards and create a new object inheriting `np.array` and override the `.__getitem__` and `.__setitem__` methods.

Or you could just use a huge matrix, or better yet, see if you can avoid having to work with matrices of unknown size.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a python generator you can use [`np.fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html):

```
def gen():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

In [11]: np.fromiter(gen(), dtype='int64')
Out[11]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

Beware if you pass an infinite iterator you will most likely crash python, so it's often a good idea to cap the length (with the count argument):

```
In [21]: from itertools import count  # an infinite iterator

In [22]: np.fromiter(count(), dtype='int64', count=3)
Out[22]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is usually to either pre-allocate (if you know the size) or build the `array` as a `list` first (using `list.append`).  But lists don't build in 2d very well, which I assume you want since you specified a "matrix."

In that case, I'd suggest pre-allocating an oversize `scipy.sparse` matrix. These can be defined to have a size much larger than your memory, and  `lil_matrix` or `dok_matrix` can be built sequentially. Then you can pare it down once you enter all of your data.

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

dummy = dok_matrix((1000000, 1000000)) # as big as you think you might need
for i, j, data in generator():
    dummy[i,j] = data
s = np.array(dummy.keys).max() + 1
M = dummy.tocoo[:s,:s] #or tocsr, tobsr, toarray . . .
```

This way you build your array as a Dictionary of Keys (dictionaries supporting dynamic assignment much better than `ndarray` does) , but still have a matrix-like output that can be (somewhat) efficiently used for math, even in a partially built state.